# Disabling selection of a node in ExtJS tree panel if the node is not a leaf node

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1 TreePanel control & want to disable selection of a node if that node is not a leaf node. Do we have any property out of the box to achieve this?

So If the node is not a leaf node, disable selection and if user click on that node, system should not fire any event (itemClick or select etc).

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is anything out of the box. The only `disableSelection` I see is on the whole `TreePanel`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no property, but you could always key on the `beforeitemclick` or `beforeselect` event (or both, depending on what you need to do). Add a handler for this event, check if the clicked node is a leaf, and if it's not, simply return false. That will halt the default behavior and effectively disable the non-leaf nodes.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-event-beforeselect

Comment: I'm facing something similar. I want to prevent a leaf node from being checked or unchecked when user clicks on it. returning false from event handlers doesn't work for me. I've tried this for these events: beforecellclick, cellclick, beforeitemclick, itemclick, beforeselect, select, selectionchange, checkchange